# Cannot match route

Tags: angular, typescript, router

So, for some reason it displays that it can't match any routes?
when i have the route im using defined here;

```
  {
    path: 'categories',
    component: CategoriesComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'categories/:id',
    component: CategoryComponent,
  }
```

and called here

```
  edit(id: number){
    this.router.navigate(['/', id]);
  }
```

> edit() is linked to a button

im not sure what im doing wrong but it displays the following error

```
core.mjs:6485 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '9'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '9'
```

but when i redirect the url manually to

> http://localhost:4200/dashboard/categories/9

it works fine, im very certain im just making a stupid mistake but it's like the devil is hiding it cs i literally cant find it.

Spare me the time im gonna take to find the mistake please.

> im new to angular

Comment: this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/categories/', id]); will work.

Answer (score 0):

Either use [`relativeTo`](https://angular.io/guide/router#specifying-a-relative-route) (if it makes sense):

```
edit(id: number) {
  this.router.navigate(['/', id], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

Or specify the route you want to navigate to with `/categories`:

```
edit(id: number) {
  this.router.navigate(['/categories', id]);
}
```